# How to concat two columns into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have this data frame in R.

```
df <- data.frame( col1 = c(3,4,'NA','NA'), col2 = c('NA','NA',1,5))
  col1 col2
1    3   NA
2    4   NA
3   NA    1
4   NA    5
```

I would like to have new column like this

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    3   NA    3
2    4   NA    4
3   NA    1    1
4   NA    5    5
```

How shall I do that?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please search.

Comment: You currently are making your data.frame so that col1 and col2 contain the _string_ 'NA'    Did you want  
`df <- data.frame( col1 = c(3,4,NA,NA), col2 = c(NA,NA,1,5))`

Comment: If you can assure that exactly one value exists per row then use: `df$col3 <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your `df` does not contains true `NA` but rather the strings `'NA'`. You probably want to have true `NA`, as per @G5W comment.

Once we have true `NA` we can use:

```
df$col3 <- ifelse(is.na(df$col1), df$col2, df$col1)
```

or, with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df$col3 <- coalesce(df$col1, df$col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmax` or `pmin` to do this (from `base R`)

```
df$col3 <- do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm=TRUE))
df$col3 
#[1] 3 4 1 5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(3L, 4L, NA, NA), col2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 
5L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```